# Overlay panel (above another)

Tags: java, swing

I am learning how to use Swing and found myself quite difficult task.

What I am trying to accomplish: I want to have panel (call it menu panel) on the left side (let's say 100px width) and the second panel (call it content panel), which takes the rest of available place.

In menu panel there are 3 buttons. When I press on of them, to the right side of menu panel (over content panel) second menu panel (submenu) should appear (and it should start in the middle of button which was pressed).

It may be hard to understand, so I've created simple draft:

[image]

I tried JLayeredPane but there were problems with resizing window (elements in Layered Pane didn't resize).

Comment: You might try a subclass of JPopupMenu.  Also, examine the source code of JComboBox and see how they use the pop-up menu there.

Answer (score 4):

`JLayeredPane` miss implementations for `LayoutManager`, you have to `setPreferredSize` or `setBounds` manually for sizing/place `JComponents`,

there is one possible workaround you can add `ComponentListener` to the `JFrame`, then on `componentResized(ComponentEvent e)` you can resize/replace `JComponent(s)` to the desired `Bounds`

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class LayeredPaneWithOverlap {

    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 10);
    private JPanel textPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JTable table = new JTable(30, 5);
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    private JLayeredPane layer = new JLayeredPane();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame with resiziable JLayeredPane");

    public void makeUI() {
        textArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        textArea.setText("Frame with resiziable JLayeredPane");
        textPanel.setOpaque(false);
        textPanel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Font font = textArea.getFont();
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = textArea.getFontMetrics(font);
        int h = fontMetrics.getHeight() + frame.getInsets().top + 
                textPanel.getInsets().top + textArea.getInsets().top
                + textArea.getInsets().bottom;
        scroll.setBounds(0, h, 400, 300);
        layer.add(textPanel, new Integer(2));
        layer.add(scroll, new Integer(1));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resizeAll();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(layer);
        resizeAll();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void resizeAll() {
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        int w = frame.getWidth() - insets.left - insets.right;
        int h = frame.getHeight() - insets.top - insets.bottom;
        textPanel.setSize(w, h);
        scroll.setSize(w, h - scroll.getY());
        layer.revalidate();
        layer.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayeredPaneWithOverlap().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This works very nice. But I have a question. Why in this line textPanel.setSize(w, h); do you set textPanel height as frame height? And textPanel is not screens height (its height remains the same).

Comment: there is about fill JComponents to the JFrame, you can play with Insets by uisng setSize/setBounds you can set desired/expected size locations relative to the parent

Answer (score 3):

You can set a layoutmanager for the layered pane, javax.swing.OverlayLayout uses the full available space and allows resizing.

```
JLayeredPane layer = new JLayeredPane();
layer.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(layer));
```

You probably don't want the submenu to occupy the fullspace.  To avoid it you can override its get…size-methods.  Or you can add a second LayeredPane (for it's transperancy and it's layoutmanager), set a normal BoxLayout and use a spacer.

```
JPanel normalContents = new JPanel();
layer.add(normalContents, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
JLayeredPane subMenuAuxiliaryLayer = new JLayeredPane()
subMenuAuxiliaryLayer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subMenuAuxiliaryLayer, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
layer.add(subMenuAuxiliaryLayer, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
JPanel submenuContents = new JPanel();
subMenuAuliliaryLayer.add(submenuContents);
subMenuAuxiliaryLayer.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
contentPanel.setLayout(null); // Absolute positioning of children.

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    final JButton btn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    final int buttonY = btn.getY(); // Must be final for usage in new Runnable object.

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // Return fast from event handling.

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JPanel child = new JPanel();
            child.setBackground(Color.RED); // So we'll see it.
            child.setBounds(0, buttonY, 100, 300);
            contentPanel.removeAll(); // Clear content panel of prior additions.
            contentPanel.add(child); // Add a new panel.
            contentPanel.repaint(10L);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: What if I am using ie. GroupLayout in contentPanel? I was thinking about making this submenu as additional panel above all other stuff.

Comment: Then have two layered panes in the contentPanel, the one above serving for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The JLayeredPane works by defualt with no Layout manager, which means that you are using absolute positioning and no resizing. You could add a resize listener and adjust positions and size of inner components from code, as you see fit.

If you don't want to do this from code, you will need a layout manager, nothing fancy, just something to fill the container as it resizes. But here's the thing... if you add a layout manager, it will layout the components as if they are all in one layer, but most layout managers don't overlap their children so they are useless. The only one you could use is the OverlayLayout - it can also resize children. But using an OverlayLayout with JLayeredPane is overkill. You can just use OverlayLayout with a JPanel. So, yes, JLayeredPane is kind of useless. I recommend using a JPanel with an OverlayLayout instead.

Here is how to set things up so that you can have great control over almost any overlapping UI scenario out there: Using a JPanel with an OverlayLayout, have a separate transparent JPanel for each layer. In this way you can combine various LayoutManagers on different layers, by setting a diferent layout manager for each pane, including absolute positioning if necessary. Then add your visible components inside the panels representing the layers. Don't add them directly to the OverlayLayout panel. Just make sure that all of the JPanels you are using as layers have setAlignmentX and Y to center (0.5f) so that they fill the entire OverlayLayout panel as it resizes.